# Zip nested list with list in Python

Tags: python, list, nested, zip

Python newbie here. I have four lists, three of which are nested lists and one that isn't. I'm searching for a way to zip the nested lists with the list such that the zip function compares each nested list item with the corresponding item in the main list.

```
main = [1,3]
a = [[1,2,3][4,5,6]]
b = [[0,1,2][3,4,5]]
c = [[2,3,4][5,6,7]]

>>>[[[True, False, False],[False,True,False],[False,False,False]],
[[False,False,False],[True,False,False],[False,False,False]]]
```

I tried something like this:

```
abc = zip(a,b,c)
test = (x==y for x, y in zip(main,*abc)
```

but I'm getting the error message "too many values to unpack". Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not really clear how `[False, True, False]` relates to `[2, 1, 3]`

Comment: Your example lists are missing some commas. And `True` and `False` should be upper case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to `zip()` the `main` list with the already zipped `a`, `b` and `c` lists and make a nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [[[item == x for item in l] for l in lists] 
     for x, lists in zip(main, zip(a, b, c))]
[[[True, False, False], [False, True, False], [False, False, False]], 
 [[False, False, False], [True, False, False], [False, False, False]]]
```