# How to join innermost elements of a deep nested list using zip

Tags: python, list, nested, iteration, list-comprehension

Suppose that I have the following list of lists containing lists:

```py
samples = [
    # First sample
    [
        # Think 'x' as in input variable in ML
        [
            ['A','E'], # Data
            ['B','F']  # Metadata
        ],
        # Think 'y' as in target variable in ML
        [
            ['C','G'], # Data
            ['D','H'], # Metadata
        ]
    ],
    # Second sample
    [
        [
            ['1'],
            ['2']
        ],
        [
            ['3'],
            ['4']
        ]
    ]
]
```

The output that I'm after looks like the following:

```py
>>> samples
[
    ['A','E','1'], # x.data
    ['B','F','2'], # x.metadata
    ['C','G','3'], # y.data
    ['D','H','4']  # y.metadata
]
```

My question is that **does there exist a way to utilize Python's `zip` function and maybe some list comprehensions to achieve this?**

I have searched for some solutions, but for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981243/zip-nested-list-with-list-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630462/python-deep-zip) deal with using `zip` to address different lists, not inner lists.

A way to achieve this could very well be just a simple iteration over the samples like this:

```py
x,x_len,y,y_len=[],[],[],[]

for sample in samples:
    x.append(sample[0][0])
    x_len.append(sample[0][1])
    y.append(sample[1][0])
    y_len.append(sample[1][1])

samples = [
    x,
    x_len,
    y,
    y_len
]
```

I'm still curious if there exists a way to utilize `zip` over `for` looping the samples and their nested lists.

**Note that the `data` and `metadata` can vary in length across samples.**

Comment: Are the innermost lists always of length 1?

Comment: Can you modify what creates the samples in the first place?

Comment: @AKX No, they are not. They are actually variable length tensors. That, however, might not be relevant here. I'm just interested in finding out if there exists a way to combine data from similarly structured list objects.

Comment: @Sayse I'm unfortunately quite limited with my options due to using two separate frameworks with my data (`torch` and `skorch`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, one way is to use `itertools.chain` to flatten the results of `zip(samples)`:

```
from itertools import chain

new_samples = [
    list(chain.from_iterable(y)) for y in zip(
        *((chain.from_iterable(*x)) for x in zip(samples))
    )
]

print(new_samples)
#[['A', 'E', '1'], ['B', 'F', '2'], ['C', 'G', '3'], ['D', 'H', '4']]
```

**Step by step explanation**

1) First call `zip` on `samples`:

```
print(list(zip(samples)))
#[([[['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F']], [['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']]],),
# ([[['1'], ['2']], [['3'], ['4']]],)]
```

Notice that in the two lines in the output above, if the elements were flattened, you'd have the structure needed to `zip` in order to get your final results.

2) Use [`itertools.chain` to flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/5858851) (which will be much [more efficient than using `sum`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41772054/5858851)).

```
print([list(chain.from_iterable(*x)) for x in zip(samples)])
#[[['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']],
# [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]]
```

3) Now call `zip` again:

```
print(list(zip(*((chain.from_iterable(*x)) for x in zip(samples)))))
#[(['A', 'E'], ['1']),
# (['B', 'F'], ['2']),
# (['C', 'G'], ['3']),
# (['D', 'H'], ['4'])]
```

4) Now you basically have what you want, except the lists are nested. So use `itertools.chain` again to flatten the final list.

```
print(
    [
        list(chain.from_iterable(y)) for y in zip(
            *((chain.from_iterable(*x)) for x in zip(samples))
        )
    ]
)
#[['A', 'E', '1'], ['B', 'F', '2'], ['C', 'G', '3'], ['D', 'H', '4']]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that one-liner producing the zip-object? Some comments to the code might even open this up. It works well, though!

Comment: @PetteriNevavuori I added some step by step explanations

Comment: After you added that extra for-iteration this answer accompanied with clear explanation seems best to me at least. I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```py
res = [[y for l in x for y in l] for x in zip(*([x for var in sample for x in var] for sample in samples))]

print([list(i) for i in res])
```

Gives on your example:

```
[['A', 'E', '1'], ['B', 'F', '2'], ['C', 'G', '3'], ['D', 'H', '4']]
```

This basically flattens each "sample" to a list and packs that in a big list, then unbpacks that into `zip` and then packs each zipped element to a list.

Comment: What if the data varies in length across samples? Try setting `samples[0][0][0] = ['A','E']` for example. This solution only returns the first element of the most inner lists.

Comment: you didn't mention how it should handle such situation. should it be: `[['A', 'E'], '1']` or `['A', 'E', '1']`?

Comment: You are correct and I apologize for that. For some reason I first thought that it shouldn't matter, but obviously it does. I have edited the question to reflect what I'm expecting as the output.

Comment: Well, fixed it. Now it works for all lenghts in any sample, just got a little messy :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. Quite ugly, but it does use `zip`, even twice!

```
>>> sum(map(lambda y: list(map(lambda x: sum(x, []), zip(*y))), zip(*samples)), [])
[['A', '1'], ['B', '2'], ['C', '3'], ['D', '4']]
```

It is interesting to see how it works, but please don't actually use it; it is both hard to read and algorithmically bad.

Comment: This actually works with varying length samples! It is indeed really hard to read though.

Comment: @PetteriNevavuori OP mentioned that you shouldn't do this, but the reason is because using [using `sum(x, [])` to flatten a list takes quadratic time and is really inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49887692/5858851).

Comment: Especially relevant since @PetteriNevavuori uses "variable-length tensors", in which case this might actually matter, as they could be quite long in an ML context.

Comment: Now that @pault changed his response a bit, his response is most clear to me. Thanks for giving your solution though! And efficiency does indeed matter in my context.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most comfortable data structure to work with you have there. I would advise to refactor the code and choose something else than 3-times nested lists to keep the data, but if it is currently not possible, I suggest the following approach:

```
import itertools


def flatten(iterable):
    yield from itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable)


result = []
for elements in zip(*map(flatten, samples)):
    result.append(list(flatten(elements)))
```

For your example it gives:

```
[['A', 'E', '1'], 
 ['B', 'F', '2'], 
 ['C', 'G', '3'], 
 ['D', 'H', '4']]
```

Test for more than 2 samples:

```
samples = [[[['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F']],
            [['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']]],
           [[['1'], ['2']], 
            [['3'], ['4']]], 
           [[['5'], ['6']],
            [['7'], ['8']]]]
```

gives:

```
[['A', 'E', '1', '5'],
 ['B', 'F', '2', '6'],
 ['C', 'G', '3', '7'],
 ['D', 'H', '4', '8']]
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `flatten` [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) simply flattens 1 level of a nested iterable. It is based on [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) function. In `map(flatten, samples)` we apply this function to each element of `samples`:

```
>>> map(flatten, samples)
<map at 0x3c6685fef0>  # <-- map object returned, to see result wrap it in `list`:

>>> list(map(flatten, samples))
[<generator object flatten at 0x0000003C67A2F9A8>,  # <-- will flatten the 1st sample
 <generator object flatten at 0x0000003C67A2FA98>,  # <-- ... the 2nd
 <generator object flatten at 0x0000003C67A2FB10>]  # <-- ... the 3rd and so on if there are more

# We can see what each generator will give by applying `list` on each one of them
>>> list(map(list, map(flatten, samples)))
[[['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']],
 [['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']],
 [['5'], ['6'], ['7'], ['8']]]
```

Next, we can use `zip` to iterate over the flattened samples. Note that we cannot apply it on `map` object directly:

```
>>> list(zip(map(flatten, samples)))
[(<generator object flatten at 0x0000003C66944138>,),
 (<generator object flatten at 0x0000003C669441B0>,),
 (<generator object flatten at 0x0000003C66944228>,)]
```

we should [unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921872/7851470) it first:

```
>>> list(zip(*map(flatten, samples)))
[(['A', 'E'], ['1'], ['5']),
 (['B', 'F'], ['2'], ['6']),
 (['C', 'G'], ['3'], ['7']),
 (['D', 'H'], ['4'], ['8'])]

# or in a for loop:
>>> for elements in zip(*map(flatten, samples)):
...     print(elements)
(['A', 'E'], ['1'], ['5'])
(['B', 'F'], ['2'], ['6'])
(['C', 'G'], ['3'], ['7'])
(['D', 'H'], ['4'], ['8'])
```

Finally, we just have to join all the lists in each `elements` tuple together. We can use the same `flatten` function for that:

```
>>> for elements in zip(*map(flatten, samples)):
...     print(list(flatten(elements)))
['A', 'E', '1', '5']
['B', 'F', '2', '6']
['C', 'G', '3', '7']
['D', 'H', '4', '8']
```

And you just have to put it all back in a list as shown in the first code sample.